# Constructing Idiosyncratic Risk Factor

Tags: volatility, factor-models, fama-french

I am studying idiosyncratic volatility. After applying the Fama Frech 3 Factor model with its Marktet, SMB and HML factors I want to build a factor based on idiosyncratic volatility.

Can I just build a portfolio including the highest idiosyncratic volatility assets and one with the lowest idiosyncratic volatility and subtract those from each other ?

My factor would then be:

IVOL factor = excess return of highest IVOL portfolios - excess returns of lowest IVOL portfolios

I could either used the 20% highest/lowest or just build the median and then assign them to one of the portfolios.

I am not sure if this approach is correct.

Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this in an academic context? If so, the standard factor portfolio procedure is the [Fama-French](https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/f-f_factors.html) construct, which involves building 6 portfolios (split by size into 3/4/3 buckets and high/low based on your score) then average of the small and big. If you're doing this in an industry/work context, calculating average quintile/decile excess returns will suffice.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is for an academic paper.

What do you mean with "split by size into 3/4/3 buckets"?

From my understanding I would construct the portfolio just like the Fama-French HML factor which would give me instead of:

  HML = 1/2 (Small Value + Big Value) - 1/2 (Small Growth + Big Growth)

the following:        

          HML_idiosyncratic =  1/2 (Small_high idiosyncratic volatility + Big_idiosyncratic volatilty) - 1/2 (Small_low idiosyncratic volatility + Big_low idiosyncratic volatility)

Does that sound correct to you?Sorry for the formatting this is my first post here

Comment: Here is an example for B/M [https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/det_form_btm.html]. The 30%/40%/30% split is what I'm referring to. When Ken French says "Portfolios are formed on BE/ME at the end of each June using NYSE breakpoints", he meant the size bucket "breakpoints" should be based on NYSE-listed stocks, then applied to NASDAQ and Amex stocks. The reason you do this is that NYSE tends to be larger than NASDAQ and Amex. If you calculate small/big buckets using all stocks then the small bucket will contain all the NASDAQ/Amex stocks

Comment: Thank you so much!